# Error running prometheus_exporter gem in docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, prometheus

I'm trying to start the [prometheus_exporter gem](https://github.com/discourse/prometheus_exporter) with -b 0.0.0.0 parameter, in a docker container.
I get this error:

```
remote:        /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:762:in `tcp_server_sockets'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/utils.rb:65:in `create_listeners'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:127:in `listen'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:108:in `initialize'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:47:in `initialize'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/lib/prometheus_exporter/server/web_server.rb:47:in `new'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/lib/prometheus_exporter/server/web_server.rb:47:in `initialize'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/lib/prometheus_exporter/server/runner.rb:45:in `new'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/lib/prometheus_exporter/server/runner.rb:45:in `start'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/bin/prometheus_exporter:122:in `run'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/gems/prometheus_exporter-0.8.1/bin/prometheus_exporter:126:in `<top (required)>'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/bin/prometheus_exporter:23:in `load'
remote:         from /usr/local/bundle/bin/prometheus_exporter:23:in `<main>'
remote:        2021-10-29 14:39:23 +0000 Starting prometheus exporter on  0.0.0.0:9394
```

The container is built using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

RUN gem install prometheus_exporter

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9394

CMD ["-v","-b 0.0.0.0"]


ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bundle/bin/prometheus_exporter"]
```

I need this to run in its own container to collect metrics from multiple other containers, so the 0.0.0.0 bind is necessary.

It starts if the -b 0.0.0.0 parameter is not used.

Any idea?

Comment: Probably `"-b", "0.0.0.0"` need to be separate arguments.  With a single argument with an embedded space like you've shown, it's trying to read `<space>0.0.0.0` as the bind address, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you very much! That was the issue indeed.